# How to Solve this MYSQL PHP Update Function version error

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

Hi currently getting a mismatch with Id but can't find why its not receiving the table id (eg. 0,1,2, etc), the display page is showing them fine going cross eyed looking at it. Also can the table be tidied up code wise? seems messy with all the `<?php ?>` tags.

Using mysql 5.5 as far as I'm aware.

Error:

> Could not able to execute UPDATE weightsmeasures SET 1 = 'dszfxc',2 =
>   'Kilograms',10 = 'Litre',11 = 'Litre',12 = 'Ton',13 = 'vdd',14 =
>   'mega' WHERE id = 14. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '1 = 'dszfxc',2 = 'Kilograms',10 = 'Litre',11 =
>   'Litre',12 = 'Ton',13 = 'vdd',14 ' at line 1

index.php input form

```
 <div>
       <?php     $result = tablename(weightsmeasures);   ?>
         <form method="post" action="update.php">
          <div class="col-8">
             <?php  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
             echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>"; ?>
                 <td>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['WeightorMeasure']; ?>" id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" name="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
                 </td>
             <?php
             echo "</tr>";  
                 }
             ?>
          </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Update">
         </form>
      </div>
```

update.php

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$sql = "UPDATE weightsmeasures SET";
$fieldValuePairs = array();
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) 
if($key != 'id')
       $fieldValuePairs[] = "$key = '$value'";
$sql .= " ". implode(',', $fieldValuePairs)." WHERE id = $id";
```

Regards

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…”)` The procedural interface exists is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a case where you should read the error message carefully, then read it again.

It says your query looks like this:

```
UPDATE weightsmeasures SET 1 = 'dszfxc',
                           2 = 'Kilograms',
                           10 = 'Litre',
                           11 = 'Litre',
                           12 = 'Ton',
                           13 = 'vdd',
                           14 = 'mega' 
 WHERE id = 14
```

Huh? It looks like the keys in your foreach statement are numbers. For this to work they need to be column names.

Even if you can get this to work, you're tickling the dragon's tail taking data from the `$_POST` variable without checking it. Use your favorite search engine to look up "little johnny droptables."